# Reflection in Knockout.js tutorial

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

Here's the code taken from the Knockout.js tutorial site:

```
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
var self = this;
self.name = name;
self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal); 
} 

//View Model along with initialState
function ReservationsViewModel() {
var self = this; 

//Non-edible data
self.availableMeals = [
{mealName:"sandwhich", price: 0 },
{mealName: "Ribs", price:25 },
{mealName: "Steak", price: 50} 
]; 

//Edible data
self.seats = ko.observableArray([
new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0])

ko.applybindings(new ReservationsViewModel()):
```

The view:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
<td data-bind = "text:name"></td>
<td data-bind = "text: meal().mealName"></td>
<td data-bind = "text: meal().price"></td>
```

What I don't understand is why the view is calling `meal().mealName` and `meal().price`. I was expecting it to be `meal().availableMeals.mealName` and `meal().availableMeals.price`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to step 2 of 5 on the Working with Lists and Collections tutorial, the reason that you call meal().mealName and meal().price is because, if you notice, you have this representation of a SeatReservation in this code:

```
// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
}
```

Notice that one of the observable bindings is `self.meal`. What this means is that, the ReservationsViewModel has an array of SeatReservations (which is represented by self.seats and an observableArray) which, each SeatReservation contains a meal.

The only purpose of availableMeals is to provide the data that you will use to populate the meal possibilities, but it's not actually the representation of the model data itself. (availableMeals could quite easily be you reading from a database and populating the data that way).

How this works in this particular piece of code is, when a seat reservation is created, it expects a name and an initialMeal. For the purposes of this tutorial, this is the addSeat function:

```
self.addSeat = function() {
    self.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", self.availableMeals[0]));
}
```

Notice that the ReservationsViewModel itself creates a new SeatReservation and passes in the availableMeal data (remember, this could be coming from a database) to, ultimately, populate the ViewModel so your view will update.